# http.get with a string

Tags: ruby, http

I'm trying to download af picture with http.get(string), where the string is the url. The string is unknow and changes every day. I got that past covered. If I print the string and paste it into http.get it works fine.
Why doesn't http.get care for variable string?

```
require 'net/http'
Net::HTTP.start("apod.nasa.gov") { |http|
  resp = http.get("/apod/")
  resp.body.each{|line|
  if(line =~ /.jpg/)
    line.sub!("<a href=","")
    line.gsub!("\"","")
    resp = http.get(line)
    open("pic.jpg", "wb") { |file|
       file.write(resp.body)
    }
    break;
  end
  }
}
```

sub with

```
    resp = http.get('/image/1011/cygnusNeb_geissinger1200.jpg')
```

and it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, got it now. The string line should be chomped

```
require 'net/http'
Net::HTTP.start("apod.nasa.gov") { |http|
  resp = http.get("/apod/")
  resp.body.each{|line|
  if(line =~ /.jpg/)
    line.sub!("<a href=","")
    line.gsub!("\"","")
    line = "/" + line.chomp
    resp = http.get(line)
    open("apod.jpg", "wb") { |file|
       file.write(resp.body)
    }
    break;
  end
  }
}
```